# Variable sized items with incremental loading

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

So I have a feed of items that is automatically updated on scrolling to the edge of my GridView with IncrementalLoader. What I want to do is to make them with different sizes. For example 1 big item 2x2, and then 4 small items 1x1 and so on.

I learned how to make my own VariableSizedWrapGrid with custom ColSpan and RowSpan for each item.

The issue is: VariableSizedWrapGrid requires static items which are already loaded. So I can't use both...

Any solution how to make them both work at the same time?

Comment: Are you saying that you data is placed in the VariableSizedWrapGrid in XAML?    Have you tried binding the data?

Comment: @WaltRitscher My data is binded and the IncrementalLoader is working. If I scroll the the right edge new items are loaded. But this is for equal items. When I tried adding VariableSizedWrapGrid they won't show.. They can't be parsed or something. And the same code is working for a static list of items, pre-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it on my own. I used this tutorial for the variable sized items:
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

And then I got rid of IncrementalLoader. Instead, I edited a copy of the GridView template and then the ScrollViewer template (with Blend). This gave me access to the ScrollBars used at the ScrollViewer.

All I needed to do is add an event to the ScrollBar:

```
ValueChanged="HorizontalScrollBar_ValueChanged"
```

And then the functions goes like this:

```
private void HorizontalScrollBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
        ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar)sender;

        if (sb.Maximum == e.NewValue)
        {
            //Scroll is at end
            //Add items here
        }
}
```